# How can I authenticate static resources in virtual directory?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, iis

I want to authenticate user to access virtual directory that contains (MP4, SWF, MP3, Images, HTML and other static files). this virtual directory is used by another web application that exists in different server. I means below case:

Server A: Contains web application that user can access it using username and password and saved in session state.

Server B: Contains virtual directory that contains static files.

i want to give access to this virtual directory files only if this user is logged in and authenticated in Server A.

How can i achieve this and which is the best practice ti achieve that??

PS: I make aspx page or .ashx handler that authenticate user and make response.write to this file but i have problem with streaming concept and i face another problem in SWF files that embed element doesn't work fine when i gave it src=Handler.aspx?file=a001.swf

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/understanding-iis-url-authorization)

Answer (score 0):

Storing authentication state in the session state, of which the Session State is set to SQL Server (instead of inProc). http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178586.aspx Might be useful.

This way, Server A can perform the authentication function and store the authentication status into session object (which is stored in the SQL server) and when user access Server B, server B can check the session state to confirm the authentication status before allowing access to the file. You can either do URL Rewrite to point all the "authentication checker" program instead of the static file directly. If the "authentication checker" confirms that authentication is ok, it will then stream the actual static file to the client.